# How to order by largest amount of identical entries with Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `survey` where users can post `answers` and since the answers are being saved in the db as a `foreign key` for each question, I'd like to know which answer got the highest rating.

So if the DB looks somewhat like this:

```
answer_id
1
1
2
```

how can I find that the answer with an `id` of `1` was selected more times than the one with an id of `2` ?

**EDIT**

So far I've done this: 
`@question = AnswerContainer.where(user_id: params[:user_id])` which lists the things a given user has voted for, but, obviously, that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do group by and then sort

```
Select answer_id, count(*) as maxsel
From poll
Group by answer_id
Order by maxsel desc
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try:

```
YourModel.group(:answer_id).count
```

for your example return something like: `{1 => 2, 2 => 1}`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in rails documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) when you use group with count, active record "returns a Hash whose keys represent the aggregated column, and the values are the respective amounts"

> Person.group(:city).count
>      # => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }